# Clear machine-check event from /proc/sys/kernel/tainted

Tags: linux, monitoring

Let me start by saying that I assume that the answer is **no-way**, but here goes ...

In monitoring our Linux systems health we check various items 
periodically.  This includes reading `/proc/sys/kernel/tainted` and alerting 
if the value within is not zero.

Often it looks like this:

- We read the value 16 out of /proc/sys/kernel/tainted, which indicates 
  that a machine-check occurred.
- Additional digging shows also:

  - `/var/log/messages` contains:

    `Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint`
    `Machine check events logged`
  - and `/var/log/mcelog`  contains

```
      Hardware event. This is not a software error.
      MCE 0
      CPU 6 BANK 10 
      MISC 90840800080148c ADDR 89a6a0c40 
      TIME 1383328318 Fri Nov  1 13:51:58 2013
      MCG status:
      MCi status:
      Corrected error
      MCi_MISC register valid
      MCi_ADDR register valid
      MCA: MEMORY CONTROLLER MS_CHANNEL2_ERR
      Transaction: Memory scrubbing error
      STATUS 8c00004a000800c2 MCGSTATUS 0
      MCGCAP 1000c12 APICID 20 SOCKETID 1 
      CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 45
```

This seems to me like a soft error, memory sometimes has errors and 
self-corrects and other than tracking the number of incidents, the 
operator shouldn't have to do anything.

Now the log above notes "Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint".
This I read to mean that the kernel doesnt want to mislead anyone about 
and software component because the hardware is "known to be bad".

This clears if we reboot, but if the number of incidents is low there is 
no real reason to reboot we would like to avoid items (not that reboot is 
the right course of action for high incidents, fixing the 
hardware/environmental issues would make sense, then reboot), but would 
still like to use this as a mechanism to alert about potential issues.  SO 
my question is ...

**Is there a way to clear this bit out of /proc/sys/kernel/tainted?**

p.s. Again, I only intend to reset this if the incidents are infrequent (See [here](http://www.mcelog.org/faq.html#2))

Comment: Replacing the defective RAM and rebooting is what you should be doing. Resetting state just so you can get _another_ alert about the defective RAM later doesn't seem sane...

Comment: @MichaelHampton - I tried to distinguish in my question good from bad hardware.  I am under the impression that even good hardware will have these soft, correctable errors.  If they happen infrequently its probably not bad (lets say once every other day).  If they happen regularly/frequent then the hardware is probably bad.   See http://www.mcelog.org/faq.html#2

Comment: Looking here, http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32.9/kernel/panic.c, and seeing where and how the static `tainted_mask`, I would say that this is not possible, but would still love to hear about any best-practices for this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, will take anything that adds valuable info

As I mentioned in my comment above, by looking at the kernel code [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32.9/kernel/panic.c) it is not possible.

It seems reasonable considering the history of "tainted", initially used to indicate that the kernel is impure due to non-compliant (non GPL) modules.  This however is a pain as I noted in my other comment, certain memory issues self-correct, and should probably NOT set that taint bit  (or at least allow to clear that specific bit).